# save for web and devices "the directory name is invalid"

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I press save in the "Save for Web & Devices" window it says:

> "Could not complete this operation. The directory name is invalid."

How can I correct this, so that it opens a file dialog once again?

Windows 7 & Photoshop CS5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the `Adobe Save for Web CS5 Prefs` file is one way.

Windows 7:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Plugins\Adobe Save for Web
>   CS5\Photoshop\Adobe Save for Web CS5 Prefs